# Safari: no Inspectable applications

Tags: ios, cordova, mobile-safari

I have a phoneGap application that I'm developing. I have been running it on an iPad in iOS7. I can use the safari web inspector no problem. But I tried inspecting it on another iPad and saw "no inspectable applications". In Settings > Safari, the web inspector is on. Why won't it work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To inspect an app with Safari's web inspector, the device needs to have a development provisioning profile for that app installed.