# Debugging JavaScriptCore with Safari, in macOS app

Tags: macos, javascriptcore

I have made a simple Hello World app for OSX that creates a context group, a context, runs a script and calls my own function, using the C-APIs, all good.

But what I can't do, is get my app/JSContext to appear in Safari's Inspectable Applications list. (It's just empty)

I can't tell if this is supposed to be automatic, or if I need to enable something in a context, VM etc (Couldn't find any references to being debuggable/inspectable in docs, headers)

This project claims to do it (based on screenshots in the wiki), but looking through the code I couldn't see any specific configuration options, settings etc
https://github.com/kasper/phoenix

This answer suggests iOS apps need to be signed... could that be necessary for macOS apps, too?
[Safari: no Inspectable applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21051793/safari-no-inspectable-applications)

Using Xcode 10B61, Safari 11.1.2, OSX 10.13.6

Has anyone managed to debug a macOS app with Safari?

Comment: Some followup from the author of that project; https://twitter.com/kasper/status/1080507639451340800

Comment: `I was wondering how to get it working myself as well, but it just automatically started working after building with some specific Xcode 9 version. The app is indeed signed with a Developer ID certificate, but it doesn’t seem to be clear whether this is a requirement or not.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I signed the application with my Apple Dev account, (I had renewed it for a different reason after I posted this question) and it appeared in Safari, (and break'd, to let me debug) and worked great!

Answer (score 0):

If you want your released app (i.e. not running in Xcode's debugger) to be able to use the Safari Web Inspector debugger when running JSC code, you need to add `com.apple.security.get-task-allow` to your entitlements.

**Caveat:** You can't get an app with that entitlement notarized by Apple.

Which means you will probably have to deliver both a notarized app without JS debugging, and one without notarization that allows debugging.